# Angular js : element.val is not working in directive link function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I a trying to update scope.answers value on change event. but not able to current changed value in link function.

directive

```
    function textControlDir()
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            require:'ngModel',
            /*scope: {
                queObj: '=',
                selectedAns: '='
                },*/
            template: '<div class="form-group">\n\
<label for="{{queObj._attributeName}}" class="col-sm-5 control-label">{{queObj._text}}</label>\n\
<div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="{{name}}" class="form-control" id="{{id}}" value="{{selectedAns}}"></div>\n\
</div>'
            ,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs,ngModel)
            {
                var queObj = scope.que.QuestionData;
                scope.queObj = scope.que.QuestionData; 
                scope.name = queObj._attributeName;
                scope.id = queObj._attributeName;
                var selectedAns = '';
                if(scope.answers)
                {
                   selectedAns = scope.answers[scope.name];
                }
                if(selectedAns && selectedAns != '')
                {
                    scope.selectedAns = selectedAns;
                }
                else
                {
                    scope.selectedAns = scope.queObj._pageAttributes.defaultValue;
                }

                element.bind('change',function(){
                    scope.answers[scope.name] = document.getElementById(scope.id).value;//element.value();
                    console.log(scope.answers[scope.name]);
                    scope.$apply();
                })
            }
        };
    }
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="que in questions[$state.current.name]">
                        <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'text'" >
                            <text-control-dir data-que-obj="que.QuestionData" data-ng-model="answers[que.QuestionData._attributeName]"></text-control-dir>
                        {{answers[que.QuestionData._attributeName]}}
                        </div>  
                        <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'select'" >
                            <select-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></select-control-dir>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'radio'" >
                            <radio-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></radio-control-dir>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'hidden' && que.QuestionData._attributeName != 'CBQ'" >
                            <hidden-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></hidden-control-dir>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

In $scope.questions have all question, I am looping in index.html. for each question i am creating a input. if $scope.answers have value for particular input I am showing in input box. this much is working. Now I want set value in answers if user changes anything in input box.

Below code is not working of directive (element.val; gives undefined)

```
                element.bind('change',function(){
                scope.answers[scope.name] = document.getElementById(scope.id).value;//element.value();
                console.log(scope.answers[scope.name]);
                scope.$apply();
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

[jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) object has `val` *method* you need to call:

```javascript
scope.answers[scope.name] = element.val();
```

Comment: TypeError: element.value is not a function

Comment: Sorry, it's val which is a function.

Comment: this prints function(arg1,arg2) In my above code how can i get input box value

Comment: scope.answers[scope.name] = document.getElementById(scope.id).value; is working fine, but i don't think it is right way to do it.

Comment: Can you create a minimal demo with the issue? What you posted is too big, I couldn't find where you have this problem.